# How do you change the values of a colorbar without changing the coloring of the plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, colorbar

I am wondering if there is a way to change the values of a colorbar in a `pcolormesh` plot without changing the colors of the plot itself. When I manually set the values of the colorbar it always changes how it draws the picture. The original image is below:

[image]

The picture looks right, but I would like to have the colorbar match the y-axis to the first plot. So, I manually changed `vmin/vmax` to those values. What I get instead is

[image]

Clearly, it is taking the values of the image, which are all about zero, relatively speaking. Is there an easy way to manually adjust the displayed values of the colorbar without changing how it draws the image?

My original code for the first image is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

CF = 2400
fs = 100

plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))

ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
plt.ylabel('Amplitude [dBm]')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [MHz]')
plt.plot(freqArray, dbmArray)

ax2 = plt.subplot(212, sharex = ax1)
f, time, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(dataArray, fs, nfft=4096)
plt.gca().set_xlim([min(f+CF), max(f+CF)])
plt.pcolormesh(f+CF, time*(1e-3), Sxx.T) 
plt.xlabel('Frequency [MHz]')
plt.ylabel('Time [ms]')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

For the second image, the only difference is

```
plt.pcolormesh(f+CF, time*(1e-3), Sxx.T, vmin=min(dbmArray), vmax=max(dbmArray))
```

Comment: Just change the tick labels of the colorbar: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html

Comment: I believe you have an XY problem. You might want to change the colorbar to correspond to another plot's y axis, but the question is, why do you need to do this to begin with? This would only make sense if the two plots (the 1d and the 2d one) plot the same thing, or at least comparable. The solution is to convert your data to have comparable dimensions. Your 1d plot is in decibels, your 2d plot is in whatever `signal.spectrogram()` returns. You have to make the two correspond to each other, and that will automatically solve your problem. Your two plots are probably related in a nonlinear way.